# WinForms WebBrowser control Url poperty not updating

Tags: .net, winforms, webbrowser-control, c#-6.0

My Windows Forms project contains a `WebBrowser` control.
When I try to change the Browsers `Url` property, it doesn't change.

```
Uri url = new Uri(someString);
myWebBrowser.Url = url;
MessageBox.Show((myWebBrowser.Url == url).ToString()); // the message box says 'false'
```

Why is the property not changing and how do I get it to change?

Comment: You have to compare your URI to the `WebBrowser.Url` in the `Navigated` event; before that, it may be `null` (also in the `Navigating event` - this property value is read from the underlying AxIWebBrowser object's `LocationURL`, which is updated later). The browser navigation may also be redirected (e.g., to reach specific language pages), so maybe set a base URI you can compare with enough confidence -- As a note, the WebBrowser Control is actually deprecated, you should move to [WebView2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webview2/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so it takes time for the property to change after you set it.

Also setting the URL isn't the best way to change the webpage.
Using `myWebBrowser.Navigate(url);` is better.